# CS50 week 5: Speller

Tags: c, cs50

I'm doing cs50x and on week 5's problem set I keep getting this error message 'error: incompatible pointer types passing 'FILE *' (aka 'struct _IO_FILE *') to parameter of type 'const char *' [-Werror,-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
while (scanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)' when implementing the load function and I can't quite understand what am I doing wrong... Can someone help me please?

[image]

Comment: `scanf` doesn't read from a `FILE*`, maybe you meant `fscanf`?

Comment: `while (scanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)` should be `while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) == 1)` Either you need `fscanf` or you need to remove the `FILE*` argumnt.

Comment: Compiler warnings would reveal this.

Comment: Welcome! Please post code as **text**, the shortest *complete* code that shows what you have tried. The best way to do that is by copy/paste, after you check it compiles and does exhibit the behaviour described. May I suggest you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "Unable to open %s\n" is not a useful error message.  Tell the user what happened, and write error messages to stderr. `perror(dictionary)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to replace **scanf** by **fscanf** in your load function. Btw, CS50 is a great course. I completed it about a month ago.